# Take view file (haml) partial in Gem and use in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, view

I've created a gem that has a file in the `app/views/merchants_support/navigation.html.haml` location and I want to use this as a partial in my rails app.

I found a stack overflow that suggested I could do something like this: `= render partial: "merchants_support/navigation"`

This obviously didn't work. Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Comment: Is `app/` your rails directory or your gem directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `navigation.html.haml` to `_navigation.html.haml` because all partions should start with `_` symbol.

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) is detail information about this convention.

Answer (score 0):

For [rendering arbitrary files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render), you can write:

```
render file: "/path/to/rails_apps/your_app/path/to/your/file"
```

> The :file option takes an absolute file-system path.

So, you can do:

```
<%= render file: Rails.root.join("app/path/to/your/file") %>
```

Or, maybe this is better:

```
<%= render file: Rails.root.join(*"app/path/to/your/file".split('/')) %>
```

If the file you want to render is a view in another controller(which is what your path looks like), then you can simply do:

```
 <%= render template: "merchants_support/navigation" %>
```